# How to perform Search function in vb.net asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to implement the search function in my ASP.NET using VB

These are my codes but i had some error in the "LIKE" query. I'm abit confused about the SQL query. Please help, thanks.

```
Dim searchOwnerSql As String =
        "SELECT Owners.name, Owners.age, Cars.platenumber FROM Owners INNER JOIN Cars LIKE @a"
    searchOwnerCmd = New SqlCommand(searchOwnerSql, conn)

Protected Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    Dim search As String = SearchTextBox.Text

    searchOwnerCmd.Parameters.Clear()
    searchOwnerCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", "%" & search & "%")

    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(searchOwnerCmd)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(ds, "search")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("search")
    totalCarsGridView.DataSource = dt
    totalCarsGridView.DataSourceID = Nothing
    totalCarsGridView.DataBind()
    If (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
        Response.Write("SUCCESS")
    Else
        Response.Write("FAILED")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong, it should be something like this:

**SELECT**... **FROM** LeftTable l 
**INNER JOIN** RightTable r 
**ON** l.[SomeKey] = r.[SomeKey] 
**WHERE** l.[FilteredColumn] **LIKE** '%seachedValue%'

You should learn more about SQL in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ for example

If your database tables are something like this:

```
   --------------
   | TABLE Cars |
   --------------
   CarId int,
   PlateNumber varchar(50),
   OwnerID int

   ----------------
   | TABLE Owners |
   ----------------
   OwnerID int,
   [Name] varchar(50),
   Age int
```

And you want to search for a specific PlateNumber, the SQL Query should be:

```
   SELECT Owners.name, Owners.age, Cars.PlateNumber FROM Owners 
   INNER JOIN Cars 
   ON Owners.OwnerID = Cars.OwnerID 
   WHERE Cars.PlateNumber LIKE @a
```

Comment: sorry I'm confused what is FilteredKey and what should I put as FilteredKey

Comment: FilterKey is some column in one of the two tables, if you have in the Cars Table a Column name Model and you like to filter all the cars that contains Sport in the their name you will have: ... WHERE Model Like '%Sport%'